# NullPointerException because of the same hibernate constructor

Tags: java, hibernate, entitymanager

I am using `hibernate 4.2.0`. I am having the following class:

```
@Entity
public class TestData {

    @Id    
    @GeneratedValue    
    private Long id;
    private String customerNr;
    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;


    /**
     * 
     */
    public TestData() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @param customerNr
     */
    public TestData(String customerNr) {
        super();
        this.customerNr = customerNr;
    }

    /**
     * @param id
     * @param customerNr
     * @param firstName
     * @param lastName
     */
    public TestData(Long id, String customerNr, String firstName,
            String lastName) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.customerNr = customerNr;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    //getter and setter etc.

}
```

To get all customerNr I am using the following query:

```
@Transactional
    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    public List<TestData> getCustomerNrFilter(String customerNr) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<TestData> criteria = cb.createQuery(TestData.class);
        //which table we want to fetch
        final Root root = criteria.from(TestData.class);
        //create statement
        criteria.select(cb.construct(TestData.class, root.get("customerNr"))).distinct(true);
        // Pass the criteria list to the where method of criteria query
        criteria.where(cb.and((Predicate[]) criteriaList.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
        // Order by clause
        criteria.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("customerNr")));
        return em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    }

    public List createWhereCritera(String customerNr, CriteriaBuilder cb,
            final Root root) {
        // This list will contain all Predicates (where clauses)
        List criteriaList = new ArrayList();
        // CustomerNr: where condition: TestData.CustomerNr like '%'
        Predicate predicateFirstName = cb.like(cb.upper(root.get("customerNr")),customerNr);
        criteriaList.add(predicateFirstName);
        return criteriaList;
    }
```

As I see the customerNr uses this constructor to get my data:

```
/**
 * @param customerNr
 */
public TestData(String customerNr) {
    super();
    this.customerNr = customerNr;
}

However, using the same query for `firstName`:

@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public List<TestData> getCustomerNrFilter(String firstName) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<TestData> criteria = cb.createQuery(TestData.class);
    //which table we want to fetch
    final Root root = criteria.from(TestData.class);
    //create statement
    criteria.select(cb.construct(TestData.class, root.get("firstName"))).distinct(true);
    // Pass the criteria list to the where method of criteria query
    criteria.where(cb.and((Predicate[]) criteriaList.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
    // Order by clause
    criteria.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("firstName")));
    return em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
}

public List createWhereCritera(String firstName, CriteriaBuilder cb,
    final Root root) {
    // This list will contain all Predicates (where clauses)
    List criteriaList = new ArrayList();
    // firstName: where condition: TestData.firstName like '%'
    Predicate predicateFirstName = cb.like(cb.upper(root.get("firstName")),firstName);
    criteriaList.add(predicateFirstName);
    return criteriaList;
}



However, firstName also tries to use the customerNr constructor to get my data:

/**
 * @param customerNr
 */
public TestData(String customerNr) {
    super();
    this.customerNr = customerNr;
}
```

Right now, giving the data back gives me a `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`, because only the `customerNr` is queried and not the `firstName`.

I cannot really create two constructors of the same type, because then I would have a `duplicated method`. Furthermore, leaving the constructor out gives me the exception `no appropriate constructor`

Any recommendations what I should do?

**UPDATE 1**

Commenting all constructors out gives me:

```
Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.Application.domain.TestData] [select distinct new com.Application.domain.TestData(generatedAlias0.customerNr) from com.Application.domain.TestData as generatedAlias0 where ( upper(generatedAlias0.customerNr) like :param0 ) and ( upper(generatedAlias0.firstName) like :param1 ) ...
```

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE 2**

My whole stacktrace:

```
3408 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter  -  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.Application.domain.TestData]
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.Application.domain.TestData]
3408 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter  -  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.Application.domain.TestData]
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.Application.domain.TestData]
 Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.Application.domain.TestData]
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.Application.domain.TestData]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processConstructor(HqlSqlWalker.java:1019)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2279)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2145)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1451)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:571)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1777)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler.compile(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:587)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.Application.dao.TestDaoImpl.getCustomerNrTest(TestDaoImpl.java:137)
    at com.Application.dao.TestDaoImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$a62bf500.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.Application.dao.TestDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6ca0bd06.getCustomerNrTest(<generated>)
    at com.Application.service.TestServiceImpl.getCustomerNrTest(TestServiceImpl.java:39)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainTabPanel.placeSelectionWithButtons(MainTabPanel.java:145)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainTabPanel.createLayout(MainTabPanel.java:119)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainWindow.createTabBar(MainWindow.java:132)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainWindow.makeLayout(MainWindow.java:182)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainWindow.access$1(MainWindow.java:172)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainWindow$4.run(MainWindow.java:197)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForTests(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForTest(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Cause:
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.Application.domain.TestData
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.getConstructor(ReflectHelper.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processConstructor(HqlSqlWalker.java:1019)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2279)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2145)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1451)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:571)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1777)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler.compile(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:587)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.Application.dao.TestDaoImpl.getCustomerNrTest(TestDaoImpl.java:137)
    at com.Application.dao.TestDaoImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$a62bf500.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.Application.dao.TestDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6ca0bd06.getCustomerNrTest(<generated>)
    at com.Application.service.TestServiceImpl.getCustomerNrTest(TestServiceImpl.java:39)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainTabPanel.placeSelectionWithButtons(MainTabPanel.java:145)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainTabPanel.createLayout(MainTabPanel.java:119)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainWindow.createTabBar(MainWindow.java:132)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainWindow.makeLayout(MainWindow.java:182)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainWindow.access$1(MainWindow.java:172)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainWindow$4.run(MainWindow.java:197)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForTests(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForTest(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.Application.domain.TestData] [select distinct new com.Application.domain.TestData(generatedAlias0.CustomerNr) from com.Application.domain.TestData as generatedAlias0 where ( upper(generatedAlias0.CustomerNr) like :param0 ) and ( upper(generatedAlias0.City) like :param1 ) and ( upper(generatedAlias0.Country) like :param2 ) and ( upper(generatedAlias0.UseType) like :param3 ) and ( upper(generatedAlias0.ProjStat) like :param4 ) order by generatedAlias0.CustomerNr asc]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1374)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler.compile(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:587)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.Application.dao.TestDaoImpl.getCustomerNrTest(TestDaoImpl.java:137)
    at com.Application.dao.TestDaoImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$a62bf500.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.Application.dao.TestDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6ca0bd06.getCustomerNrTest(<generated>)
    at com.Application.service.TestServiceImpl.getCustomerNrTest(TestServiceImpl.java:39)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainTabPanel.placeSelectionWithButtons(MainTabPanel.java:145)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainTabPanel.createLayout(MainTabPanel.java:119)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainWindow.createTabBar(MainWindow.java:132)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainWindow.makeLayout(MainWindow.java:182)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainWindow.access$1(MainWindow.java:172)
    at com.Application.gui.scenarioSelection.MainWindow$4.run(MainWindow.java:197)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForTests(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForTest(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.Application.domain.TestData] [select distinct new com.Application.domain.TestData(generatedAlias0.CustomerNr) from com.Application.domain.TestData as generatedAlias0 where ( upper(generatedAlias0.CustomerNr) like :param0 ) and ( upper(generatedAlias0.City) like :param1 ) and ( upper(generatedAlias0.Country) like :param2 ) and ( upper(generatedAlias0.UseType) like :param3 ) and ( upper(generatedAlias0.ProjStat) like :param4 ) order by generatedAlias0.CustomerNr asc]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1777)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:452)
    ... 40 more
```

**UPDATE 3**

Changing my method gives me the following exception:

```
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public List<TestData> getCustomerNrFilter(String firstName) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<TestData> criteria = cb.createQuery(TestData.class);
    //which table we want to fetch
    final Root root = criteria.from(TestData.class);
    //create statement
    criteria.select(root.get("firstName")).distinct(true);
    // Pass the criteria list to the where method of criteria query
    criteria.where(cb.and((Predicate[]) criteriaList.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
    // Order by clause
    criteria.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("firstName")));

    List<String> resultList = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList(); // EXCPETION: Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<TestData> to List<String>

    return resultList;
}

public List createWhereCritera(String firstName, CriteriaBuilder cb,
    final Root root) {
    // This list will contain all Predicates (where clauses)
    List criteriaList = new ArrayList();
    // firstName: where condition: TestData.firstName like '%'
    Predicate predicateFirstName = cb.like(cb.upper(root.get("firstName")),firstName);
    criteriaList.add(predicateFirstName);
    return criteriaList;
}
```

Comment: Create the object **empty**, then start using setters.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Please have a look at my update. I am receiving the exception from before, `Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class `. Btw what do you exactly mean by using setters? How should my query change?

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace. We cannot even check where the problem arises.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thx for your reply! I added my stacktrace, in update 2.

Comment: Simply don't use cb.construct(), get the result as a `List<String>` (if I'm not mistaken), iterate over the rows, and call the constructor you want by yourself.

Comment: @JBNizet Thx for your reply! Could you provide me an example, with my code? I do not really get what you mean!

Comment: Use `criteria.select(root.get("firstName")).distinct(true)`, and it should return you a List<String> (AFAIK). Transform this `List<String>` to a `List<TestData>` as you wish.

Comment: @JBNizet Thx for your answer changing this, gives me a `List<String>` back, however, that does not work: `List<String> resultList = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();`, because it says that, `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<TestData> to List<String>`

Comment: Use a for loop to transform this List<String> into a List<TestData>.

Comment: @JBNizet Thx for your answer! List<String> is totally ok for me, however, it seems that `em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();` does not return a `List<String>`, like you mentioned. Any recommendations, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Post your updated code. And tell us what the list actually contains. Printing it should tell it.

Comment: @JBNizet Thx for your answer! Here is the list output: resultList: `[John, Mark, Matt, Joe]` The thing that is weird to me is, that I cannot say which type that actually is. Definitely not string...

Comment: So, it is a list containing strings. You have declared your CriteriaQuery as a CriteriaQuery<TestData>, i.e. a query that returns TestData. But it's a query returning String. So it should be declared as CriteriaQuery<String>.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Still the problem is not yet resolved, I am receiving not a list of strings, instead I am having a type mismatch: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to List<String>`, `List<String> resultList = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList().toString();`, why is this still not `List<String>`, any recommendations are highly appreciated!!!

Comment: btw I also changed: `CriteriaQuery<String> criteria = cb.createQuery(String.class);`, because using `CriteriaQuery<String> criteria = cb.createQuery(TestData.class);`, gives me back `Type mismatch: cannot convert from CriteriaQuery<TestData> to CriteriaQuery<String>`

Comment: `em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList()` is a List<String>. If you call `toString()` on any object, you get a String, obviously. Don't call toString().

Comment: @JBNizet OK, I really got it now! Sorry, for these weird questions! Thx a lot for your help!